# Datamax programming language text wrap

Tags: protocols, thermal-printer

I'm working with DPL protocol for Datamax thermal printer. I would like to know if is there a text block definition to wrap long text inside this block. The corresponding command for Zebra (ZPL) is ^FB.

Comment: Dit you find an answer since your question, or some algorithm to prepare this before sending commands to the printer ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find a solution and I switched to ZPL printers...

Comment: This could be done with an algorithm and a big fonts characters width table generating the needed DPL code using multiple text zones. I will probably publish a DPL driver project for php. Please be patient, or help me.

Comment: I encountred the same problem while working on a label designer. I found this page about Printing in a Formatted Text Box https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Printing-in-a-Formatted-Text-Box

Comment: @YouneS Did you get this to work? I have a datamax I-4208 and it does not respond to the method you posted.. it just adds the \[...] command as text on the label and does no wrapping. Any idea if this requires a specific firmware version?